# Handling exceptions in forked process

Tags: ruby, exception, sinatra, fork

I'm building a Sinatra API call that will trigger a long-running operation in a subprocess. I'm using the [exception_handler](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) gem, but don't understand how I'd use it in the forked process.

Sinatra app:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'exception_notification'

use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
  :email => {
    :email_prefix => "[Example] ",
    :sender_address => %{"notifier" <notifier@example.com>},
    :exception_recipients => %w{me@example.com},
    :delivery_method => :sendmail
  }

get '/error' do
  raise 'Bad!' # Notification gets sent
end

get '/error_async' do
  p1 = fork do
    sleep 10
    raise 'Bad! (async)' # Notification never gets sent
  end
  Process.detach(p1)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, per the [docs](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification#background-notifications):

```
get '/error_async' do

  p1 = fork do

    begin
      sleep 10
      raise 'Bad! (async)'
    rescue Exception => e
      ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception(e)
    end

  end
  Process.detach(p1)

end
```

Comment: Wow if you need to explicitly write `ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception` to send the notification then that gem is basically useless. The real benefit of a gem like this is that you get notified even though you **did not know** where your production Sinatra/Rails app was throwing an exception because you didn't anticipate it (if you did then you would have `begin/rescue`).

Comment: @Mike you're just wrapping the code that's being subbed-out to the background process- which I think actually makes sense.

Comment: True you can just do a catchall for all of the code in the new thread, seems a bit cheap but it gets the job done.